# Replacing the physical layer of MIL-STD-1553 with RS-485

Tags: rs485, mil-std-1553

I've been reading about [MIL-STD-1553](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-1553) buses, which very briefly are

- multidrop
- Manchester-encoded
- 1 Mbit/sec
- 32-station: a single "bus controller" master and multiple "bus terminals" slaves which speak only when spoken to

Given how [similar](http://www.milstd1553.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/MIL-STD-1553_Physcal_Layer_vs_RS-485.pdf) the two buses are electrically ...

**I was wondering if it's possible to replace the electrical layer with RS-485?**

This is an engineering-curiosity question for an industrial application: don't worry, it's not in a fighter jet!

Wikipedia shows a 1553 slave responding to the master's transmit instruction like this:
[image] ([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RTtoBC2.png))

Is there any reason we couldn't do this pretty much exactly with an RS-485 transceiver?  [Edit for clarification] **By which I mean replace all the 1533 transceivers, transformers and cables with RS-485 transceivers, cables, terminators, cutting at the red line of the diagram below.**

A typical 1553 transceiver looks like this:
[image]
(from [DDC-8553 datasheet](https://www.ddc-web.com/en/power/discontinued-1/bus-8553?partNumber=BUS-8553-1,%20BUS-8553-2,%20BUS-8553-3,%20BUS-8553-4,%20BUS-8553-5,%20BUS-8553-8))

It's not clear to me why the transceiver has differential connections to the the decoder and encoder (ie to the right), but I'm guessing it's for signal quality.

As far as I can tell, something like this with a classical 75176-format RS-485 transceiver should work identically as far as the interfaced device is concerned (assuming suitable RS-485 wiring, lengths, termination etc):

[image]

Any reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: I see an isolation transformer and that means good control of DC voltages on the line and I don't think RS485 pays excessive attention to this.

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka ... I've edited my question to be a little clearer: I'm not asking about signal quality or isolation etc on the bus, I'm asking if the interface into the transceiver (right-hand-side) can tell if we replace the 1533 transceivers, transformers and cables with RS-485 transeivers (with extra gates for polarity and ignoring the differential `/TXDATAIN`), and use RS-485 cables terminators etc.

Comment: The isolation transformer is also there to prevent a remote terminal that becomes short circuit (or some other fault) from interfering with the rest of the bus. There is usually a bus monitor in parallel with the remote terminal, incidentally.

Comment: @jonathanjo I expect it will work in a lot of applications but check out the NAND gate that disables transmission should both TXDATA and nTXDATA both be high.

Comment: Many thanks @Andyaka that's really helpful.  I'm not actually trying to model a particular 1533 transceiver, so matching the fault behaviour isn't my focus at the moment.

Comment: 1553 is a three state bus (+, -, zero), the 1533 decoder will expect to see all three at the proper times. RS-485 will not simulate the zero state very well. I am guessing that it will not work.

Comment: @Andyaka ... I added the gate to deal with the situation you mentioned "that disables transmission should both TXDATA and nTXDATA both be high", image updated

Comment: @Mattman944 ... thanks for comment: are you saying that during for example the 0V parts outside the transmission and in the 8.97us gap (of waveform in my question) the decoder is expecting to see RXD=0 and /RXD=0?  What do typical 1553 decoders do if they don't see that?  Log an error condition?

Comment: Yes, the decoder expects to see both RXD and /RXD = 0 in-between words. Besides errors, it may have difficulty finding the beginning of words.

Comment: @Mattman944 Thanks ... I would have expected it to be looking for the start-of-word "3-bit sync" for finding the beginning of words, but I take your point entirely.  In the situation I'm thinking of, we would be replacing the encoder/decoder as well, so should be able to work around this if it's a problem.

Comment: OK, if you are designing you own encoder/decoder, you should be able to compensate (for the missing zero state). Realize that designing an encoder/decoder is a big undertaking.